# how to change node highlight shape while creating link between two nodes (gojs)

Tags: gojs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5w1i.png)

As in the image, the nodes are circular but the highlight shape is rectangle . I want to change this rectangle shape to circular while creating link between two nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied from forum)

You could set a **portTargeted** function to set the **temporaryFromPort** or **temporaryToPort** to match the figure of the targeted port.

```
myDiagram.toolManager.linkingTool.portTargeted = function(realnode, realport, tempnode, tempport, toend) {
  if (realport === null) {
    tempport.figure = "Square";
  } else {
    tempport.figure = realport.figure;
  }
}
```

You probably want to do the same for the **RelinkingTool**.

Comment: Thanks. Works well.